# Как реализовать метод от метода с бесконечной вложенностью?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Решаю задачу, где надо сделать класс, методы которого расставляли бы соответствующие тэги в строку/строки, которые туда подаются. Одним из условий является наличие возможности применять методы друг за другом до бесконечности , т.е.`format.div.h1('text')` на выходе должно давать тоже самое, как если бы я результат `format.h1`, затем подал в `format.div`   `-->` `<div><h1>text</h1></div>`
Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом это можно сделать? Мой код:

```
class Format:
    def div(self, *args: str):
        combo = ''.join(args)
        return f'<div>{combo}</div>'

    def h1(self, *args: str):
        combo = ''.join(args)
        return f'<h1>{combo}</h1>'

    def p(self, *args: str):
        combo = ''.join(args)
        return f'<p>{combo}</p>'

    def span(self, *args: str):
        combo = ''.join(args)
        return f'<span>{combo}</span>'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Format():
    def __init__(self, string = ""):
        self.string = string
    
    
    def __call__(self, value):
        return self.string + value + self.string.replace("<", "</")
        
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return Format(f"{self.string}<{attr}>")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.string
```

Comment: Гениально! Огромное Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

а почему не попробовать сделать следующее:

класс `Format` должен возвращать не строки, а опять же элемент класса `Format`

и добавить в класс преобразование результата в строку `__str__`

тогда получится делать такие сцепки

```
class Format:
    def __init__(self, data = ""):
        self.data = data

    def __str__(self):
        return self.data

    def div(self, *args: str):
        combo = self.data + ''.join(args)
        return Format(f'<div>{combo}</div>')

    def h1(self, *args: str):
        combo = self.data + ''.join(args)
        return Format(f'<h1>{combo}</h1>')


res = Format("a").div("10").h1("20")

print(res)
```

> результат: `<h1><div>a10</div>20</h1>`

Comment: Направление правильное, но этого мало. Так просто не получится сделать API, которое нужно автору вопроса, т.е. обращение по атрибутам `format.div.h1(...)`

Answer (score 2):

К ответу Danis, небольшое дополнение, иначе закрывающие тэги идут не в правильном порядке.

```
class Format():
    def __init__(self, string='', revers_string=''):
        self.string = string
        self.revers_string = revers_string

    def __call__(self, value):
        return f'{self.string}{value}{self.revers_string}'

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return Format(f'{self.string}<{attr}>', f'</{attr}>{self.revers_string}')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.string
```

Comment: Я про это вообще забыл

Comment: Спасибо! С тэгами я уж сам разобрался :)